# How to Obtain IP Address of Connected Client in xinetd Custom Service

Tags: c, linux, xinetd

**Question:**
[xinetd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xinetd) (extended Internet services daemon) maps input to a service's standard input and output to a service's standard out.

In other words, assuming a custom TCP service written in C, data coming into port *X* is mapped to stdin of the service and stdout of the service is mapped to data coming out of port *Y*.

Again, assuming a custom TCP service written in C, is there a way for that service to determine the connecting client's IP Address?

**Web Research:**
As of the posting of this question, there are NO other questions on Stack Exchange (or elsewhere) that specifically deal with xinetd TCP services written in C attempting to determine the connecting client's IP Address.

There are similar questions:

- Dealing with PHP ([Xinetd obtain remote IP with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462128/xinetd-obtain-remote-ip-with-php)).
- Dealing with generic client/server ([Determining the IP address of a connected client on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282369/determining-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-on-the-server))

But none that answer the specific question detailed in this post.

**FOLLOW UP NOTE:** xinetd takes the *socket descriptor* associated with TCP port *X* and maps it to the service's standard input.

Being cognizant of this fact would have allowed for a better web search that resulted in the following answers:

- [Recovering IP/Port from Socket Descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186118/recovering-ip-port-from-socket-descriptor)
- [Can you determine the source IP and port from a connected TCP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296258/can-you-determine-the-source-ip-and-port-from-a-connected-tcp-socket?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with [`getpeername(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getpeername.html) on its stdin (0) or stdout (1) file descriptor.

Example: when run from `xinetd` or `inetd`, this will print the address of the client connected to its stdin:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void){
        union {
                struct sockaddr a;
                struct sockaddr_in in;
                struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
        } na;
        char host[NI_MAXHOST], port[NI_MAXSERV]; int e;
        socklen_t nl = sizeof na;
        if(getpeername(0, &na.a, &nl)) err(1, "getpeername");
        if(e = getnameinfo(&na.a, nl, host, sizeof host, port, sizeof port,
                        NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV))
                errx(1, "getnameinfo: %s", gai_strerror(e));
        switch(na.a.sa_family){
        case AF_INET:
                errx(0, "connection from %s:%s", host, port);
        case AF_INET6:
                errx(0, "connection from [%s]:%s", host, port);
        default:
                errx(0, "connection from unknown address family %d",
                        na.a.sa_family);
        }
}
```

Comment: I believe `_POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX` is defined as 255. 128 may be a tad bit small (or it may be larger than needed). Also see [Maximum hostname length on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18851234/608639).

Comment: yes, but I'm using `NI_NUMERICHOST`, so even 40 bytes should be enough  ;-)

Comment: I don't think get peername will work on an unconnected socket?